# Jquery Add Dynamic Input with limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code for add dynamic input fields to my form.

HTML:

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts">
            <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

This Worked and add input fields unlimited. now, I need to put limit for add input for example : add Only 5 input field.

How do can I create limit ?!

DEMO : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/)

Comment: Add a counter variable or just count the number of code chunks.

Comment: (OT) `id="remScnt"` should be a CLASS! You know that ID MUST be unique per page, right? Also why you use the old jQuery 1.4 ?

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in favor of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)...

Comment: @War10ck I did not see the ID's my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable within the scope of the page and use it for the max count:

```
var max = 5;

$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            if (i <= max) {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
            }
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y63en/

Comment: @War10ck Wrote me in answer that I delete for bad Quality in this question "Two problems: (1) There is no p_scnts so the for attribute on the label is useless. (2) You're appending multiple elements with the same id p_scnt. id's have to be unique.." He has reason.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a if condition to check the **var i**

JS:

```
if(i <= 5) {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
 }
```

Demo : [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arulpraba/tZPg4/10199/)

Comment: @War10ck Wrote me in answer that I delete for bad Quality in this question "Two problems: (1) There is no p_scnts so the for attribute on the label is useless. (2) You're appending multiple elements with the same id p_scnt. id's have to be unique.." He has reason.